# How to 'turn on' cljs.spec

Tags: clojurescript

How do I make sure that clojure/cljs.spec is verifying function call arguments and return values?

Say I have this function:

```
(defn my-inc [x]
  (inc x))
```

After which I have this:

```
(s/fdef my-inc
      :args (s/cat :x number?)
      :ret  number?)
```

This code compiles because `[cljs.spec.alpha :as s]` has been required.

Now I call the function so as to hopefully generate an error:

```
(my-inc "Not a number")
```

I would like to see the `fdef` being used, and see the error message stating that `my-inc` cannot be called with a string. How do I make this happen in a very general way, for instance with a setting in `project.clj` or `user.cljs`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this code in `user.cljs`:

```
(:require 
  [cljs.spec.alpha :as s]
  [cljs.spec.test.alpha :as ts])

(defn my-inc [x]
  (inc x))

(s/fdef my-inc
        :args (s/cat :x number?)
        :ret number?)

(ts/instrument)

(defn x-1 []
  (my-inc "Hi"))
```

I can call `x-1` from the cljs/figwheel REPL, and get this failure message:

> ```
> #error {:message "Call to #'cljs.user/my-inc did not conform to spec:\nIn: [0] val: \"Hi\" fails at: [:args :x] predicate: number?\n:cljs.spec.alpha/spec  #object[cljs.spec.alpha.t_cljs$spec$alpha50572]\n:cljs.spec.alpha/value  (\"Hi\")\n:cljs.spec.alpha/args  (\"Hi\")\n:cljs.spec.alpha/failure  :instrument\n", :data #:cljs.spec.alpha{:problems [{:path [:args :x], :pred cljs.core/number?, :val "Hi", :via [], :in [0]}], :spec #object[cljs.spec.alpha.t_cljs$spec$alpha50572], :value ("Hi"), :args ("Hi"), :failure :instrument}}
> ```

I can also get conformance errors when working with a *real* project running code in a browser. The errors show up in the developer's console on the browser.

Put `(ts/instrument)` at the bottom of `user.cljs` to turn instrumentation on for all namespaces for development.

*Edit*
Just in case you are hit by this problem: https://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJS-1792
- the fix is to include `[org.clojure/test.check "0.10.0-alpha2"]` (probably with a more recent version) in your `project.clj` dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`instrument`](http://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.spec.test.alpha/instrument) to check args conformance for certain symbols or all vars.

When called without arguments, `instrument` wraps all instrumentable vars into a function that checks the args before delegating to the original function.

Comment: I tried putting `(s/instrument)` at the top of the namespace, but `cljs.spec.alpha/instrument` is an undeclared Var.

Comment: I'm using a recent version. Seems like I need to require `[cljs.spec.test.alpha :as ts]` as well. I didn't realise that `instrument` was in a different namespace, as glossed over that when looking into the link.

Comment: Now when I run the project I get 'goog.require could not find: cljs.spec.test.alpha' from the figwheel heads up display.

Comment: Maybe [lein clean](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel/wiki/Quick-Start#pro-tip-use-lein-clean) will help?

Comment: I now have `(ts/instrument)` above `my-inc` and the `s/fdef`, all three the `user.cljs` so I can test from the cljs REPL. `(my-inc "hi")` returns "hi1", whereas `(inc "hi")` gives a compiler warning.

Comment: Just to be certain, `instrument` enumerates symbols in the namespace, so they have to be defined before `(instrument)` is called.
However, on a closer look, it seems that I'm not able to run `instrument` successfully with my config either. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Having `(instrument)` at the end of a namespace helped indeed. Trialling out calling spec-ed functions directly from the REPL was a bad idea it seems, but making the caller not be in the REPL (see call from `x-1` in my answer) fixed that.